# game maker studio 2: bullets don't move to the mouse direction

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I'm trying to make shooting mechanics in my game, but I can not force bullets move to the mouse direction. It just creating under player object and stay on his coordinates . Uses physics don't change situation, no matter obj_bullet just "uses physics"(and with sensor parameter as well) or not uses.

They just stay on coordinates where I created them

[image: x]

When I don't use physics on obj_bullet, bullet sprite rotating depends of mouse position but still don't move.

[image: xx]

I wrote a simple code for my bullets in "create" event of bullet

```
BulletPower=1;
bulletSpeed=10;
speed=bulletSpeed;
direction=point_direction(x,y,mouse_x, mouse_y);
direction+=random_range(-5,5);
image_angle=direction;
```

Tried to use `move_towards_point(mouse_x, mouse_y,bulletSpeed);` instead but doesn't work

Then I've made instance layer "Bullets" above all others 
and then made condition in "step" event of obj_player

```
if (mouse_check_button(mb_left)){
    instance_create_layer(x,y,"Bullet",obj_bullet);
}
```

And bullets just drop on player coordinates.
I had theory that bullet just stack in player, but even if I create bullet not on player coordinates it still doesn't work 
Also I changed axis of player and bullet sprites but still no result...

I really don't understand why it doesn't work, because I saw almost same code on youtube tutorials [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCeyiEcWRAs)
and in their case it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, I hope it help somebody. Bullets don't move because variable "speed" will not work if room using physics. You need make obj_bullet as physic object(uses physics),then write code in "create" event

```
direction=point_direction(x,y, mouse_x , mouse_y );
phy_rotation = -direction;//it's like image angle for bullets
```

and make event "step" event

```
phy_position_x += lengthdir_x(bulletSpeed, direction);
phy_position_y += lengthdir_y(bulletSpeed, direction);
```

Done! Now bullets will move.